# Get an argument of an asynchronous parent function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this:

```js
function change( event, file ) {
  console.log( "filename", file );
  //It should be '_file', not 'file'.
  files.clients( file, function( clientOfFile ) {
    console.log( "for client:", clientOfFile );
    io.sockets.socket( clientOfFile ).emit( "change" );
  } );
}

client.on( "watch", function( file ) {
   _file = base + file; //filename with path
   files.add( _file, client.id );
   fs.watch( _file, change );
} );
```

`fs.watch` passes to callback a filename without path. So I want it to get parent function argument `_file`. I thought I can use `.call`, but how to do it in callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plenty of possiblitys, one is to use `Function.prototype.bind`, if you don't need to have access to the original `this value` within the callback:

```
fs.watch( _file, change.bind({_file: _file});
```

That way you can access `_file` like

```
this._file;
```

within your callback method.

---

One word of caution: Be aware that you are using another anonymous function in your callback method for the callback of `files.clients`. `this` does not reference the same value within there. So if you want to access our newly passed `this` reference there, you need to either invoke another `.bind()` call or just store an outer reference to `this` in a local variable.

Comment: I am curious what are other possiblities?

Comment: @Hahi: well, the easiest solution would probably be to also use an anonymous function instead your `change` function as event handler. That way you would just have access to `_file` the whole way due to a closure.